# Adding a tooltip configuration to a pie chart data item in ECharts?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, echarts, ngx-echarts

Trying to add a `tooltip` property to a `data` item in this [pie chart (Stackblitz Demo)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-v7ee5w?file=src%2Fecharts.component.ts).

This is the entire `options` configuration.

```
    this.options = {
      tooltip: {
        trigger: 'item',
        formatter: '',
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: ' ',
          clockwise: true,
          type: 'pie',
          radius: ['65%', '100%'],
          center: ['50%', '50%'],
          data: [
            {
              value: 500,
              name: 'Solana',
              label: {
                position: 'center',
                formatter: '',
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: 600,
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                color: 'blue',
              },
              tooltip: {},
            },
            {
              value: 500,
              name: 'Tether',
            },
            {
              value: 1000,
              name: 'Golem',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
  }
```

The [ECharts documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-pie.data.tooltip) indicates that it should be possible.

However the demo gives the following error.

```
Error in src/echarts.component.ts (66:15)
Type '{ name: string; clockwise: true; type: "pie"; radius: string[]; center: string[]; data: ({ value: number; name: string; label: { position: "center"; formatter: string; fontSize: number; fontWeight: number; fontFamily: string; color: string; }; tooltip: {}; } | { ...; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'SeriesOption$1'.
Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
Type '({ value: number; name: string; label: { position: "center"; formatter: string; fontSize: number; fontWeight: number; fontFamily: string; color: string; }; tooltip: {}; } | { value: number; name: string; })[]' is not assignable to type '(OptionDataValueNumeric | OptionDataValueNumeric[] | PieDataItemOption)[]'.
Type '{ value: number; name: string; label: { position: "center"; formatter: string; fontSize: number; fontWeight: number; fontFamily: string; color: string; }; tooltip: {}; } | { value: number; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'OptionDataValueNumeric | OptionDataValueNumeric[] | PieDataItemOption'.
Type '{ value: number; name: string; label: { position: "center"; formatter: string; fontSize: number; fontWeight: number; fontFamily: string; color: string; }; tooltip: {}; }' is not assignable to type 'OptionDataValueNumeric | OptionDataValueNumeric[] | PieDataItemOption'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'tooltip' does not exist in type 'OptionDataValueNumeric[] | PieDataItemOption'.
```

If I change the options from using the `EChartsOption` typedlike this:

```
  options!: EChartsOption;
```

To this:

```
  options!: any
```

Then the demo compiles so I'm trying to figure out whether the documentation is wrong, or the `EChartsOption` type is wrong, or whether there is something else that I'm missing?

Comment: The documented way is defenitely possible as you can see in [this example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWszGAG0iAXMmuhgE4QDmFApqYQOQRjUC29xAvgDTEDOtEar0IBtYulQkSYAJ4hqDEIPo8p6UgEMAJhACuw2PQCsABgCkK8SS0awG0ValJYANw3ZdC2AEYTAFgAOLlhoDRYvegBlag1SAGMAC1gAUWgKCGhqFQwsXAgCZBBgXiYoaFFfLl8AXQ5uRxJnNw8vAHYAZiNg0PCGABEIUmo4sGzMHDxCJCKSyBgKkyqTWvq1Rtd3T0IjAMWQsIjklg0IbDHcycLi0vnYEUqautU1auf0DmJqlA4AbiA).

Comment: Indeed - I have a feeling that perhaps the `EChartsOption` needs to be refactored.  I'll ask on the ECharts mailing list.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/19293

Comment: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-pie.data.tooltip